# How can I evaluate the prospects of mining vs investing?

Tags: mining-profitability, altcoin, gpu-mining, investing

I have a few thousand dollars that I want to invest in cryptocurrencies now or soon, and was wondering how the current prospects look for ROI of setting up my own 6 gpu mining rig (ether/Zcash/Monero/etc...) vs buying and holding a diversified portfolio of 5-10 different cryptocurrencies. What are a few of the major pros and cons of gpu mining vs buy and hold?

Comment: This can't be answered without market speculation, which is off topic on this site.  You may want to ask your question in a different forum.

Comment: @Jestin: I think this is answerable by focussing on the general evaluation of the topic rather than the current market situation. I'd also think that we should have similar questions here already, but I'm not sure whether one focusses this specifically on mining vs investing.